# My express https server works locally but not in a docker container

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, express

I currently have two docker containers running:

```
ab1ae510f069        471b8de074c4        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp                     hopeful_bassi
2d4797b77fbf        5985005576a6        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   wizardly_cori
```

One is my client and the other (port `3001`) is my server.

The issue I'm facing is I've just added SSL to my site, but now I can't access the server. My theory is that the server needs both port 443 and port 3001 open, but I can't have `port 443` open on both containers. I can run the server via HTTP locally, so I think that also points to this conclusion.

Is there anything I can do to have both using https? The client won't talk to the server if the server uses http (for obvious reasons).

Edit:
I'm now not sure if it is to do with port 443, as I killed my client and tried to just run the server, but it still gave me connection refused:

```
docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped -p 3001:3001 -p 443:443 471b8de074c4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the port 443 for a docker container, it means that a docker-managed tool will be started. This (anyways, highly sup-optimal) tool will forward the TCP requrest to your host port 443 to the container.

If you want two containers to use the port 443, docker would want to start this portforwarder twice, on the same port. As your docker output shows, it could happen only once. Maybe digging (deeply) in the (nearly non-existent) docker logs, you can see also the relevant error message.

The problem you've found is not docker-dependant, it is the same problem what you would face also in a container-less environment - you simply can't start multiple service processes listening on the same TCP port.

Also the solution is coming from the world before the containers.

You need a central proxy service, *this would listen on your port 443, and forward the requests - depending on the asked virtualhost - to the corresponding container*.

Dig into the docker containers, it is nearly sure that such a https forward proxy exists. This third container will forward the requests where you want. Of course you will need to configure it.

From that moment, you don't even need to have https in your containers (although you can if you want), what helps a lot in productive, correctly certified ssl environments. Only your proxy will need the certificates. So:

```
                 /---> container A (tcp:80)
tcp:443 -- proxy
                 \---> container B (tcp:80)
```